# How do I convert JSON hierarchical tree data into a two dimensional table using jq?

Tags: tree, jq

I have a **hierarchical** tree of JSON data as per the example below, and I need to convert this into a two dimensional table in text format, with the semantics of SQL join.

*Note: there are answers to the question "How do I convert data in a two dimensional JSON array into a two dimensional table in text format", this question is about hierarchical JSON data, not two dimensional arrays.*

The input JSON:

```
[
    [
        [
            [
                "machine.example.com"
            ],
            [
                {
                    "VolumeId": "vol-070061259e62b931d",
                    "AttachTime": "2017-11-29T00:58:46.000Z",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "Status": "attached"
                },
                {
                    "VolumeId": "vol-070b6ecf34107389f",
                    "AttachTime": "2017-11-29T00:58:46.000Z",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "Status": "attached"
                },
                {
                    "VolumeId": "vol-0d6188182333509a2",
                    "AttachTime": "2017-11-29T01:30:51.000Z",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                    "Status": "attached"
                },
                {
                    "VolumeId": "vol-0653708f578c13e36",
                    "AttachTime": "2017-11-29T01:31:06.000Z",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                    "Status": "attached"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The desired output:

```
machine.example.com vol-070061259e62b931d
machine.example.com vol-070b6ecf34107389f
machine.example.com vol-0d6188182333509a2
machine.example.com vol-0653708f578c13e36
```

Can jq do this?

Comment: Yes.  If you need further help, it would be advisable to ask a specific question regarding your attempt to use jq to solve the problem.

Comment: Here is a crappy solution that gets close
 `key=$(cat tmp.json | jq -r .[][][][] | head -1);`
`cat tmp.json | jq .[][][][] | sed 1d | jq --arg key "$key" '{key: $key, vol: .VolumeId}'`

Answer (score 0):

Drill down to the "lines" of data then build out the result values.

```
$ jq -r '.[][] | "\(.[0][]) \(.[1][].VolumeId)"' input.json
machine.example.com vol-070061259e62b931d
machine.example.com vol-070b6ecf34107389f
machine.example.com vol-0d6188182333509a2
machine.example.com vol-0653708f578c13e36
```